# what is the different between using if else and if else if else (deep condition) in complexity of code?

Tags: conditional-statements, time-complexity

i get confused  after i ready many articles about complexity specially with complexity of condition in many website i been looking to know my solution for my answer for 1 hour but none of website provide it so i just want to know what is the best when i use conditions like

```
int x = 10;
if(x<1)
 cout<<"done";
else
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
   cout<<"done";
   }
```

i know that  in this case we will choice the higher complexity of both of them and it will be big(O) which is O(N) 
but what about if i use else if is it will be the same as i think of above code ?

```
 int x = 10;
if(x<1)
 cout<<"done";
else if(x> 20)
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
   cout<<"done";
   }
else
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
   cout<<"done";
   }
```

does it make this example O(N) too  like the above example

**please if you have any resources or links that provide good content of algorithm complexity write it after you answer my question , thank you**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Also check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask. It is unclear what you are asking. If the `if`/`else` block are relevant to your `O(n)` analysis depends on the actual algorithm.

Comment: _Code Complexity_ and big-O different concerns. You can have two variations of code that are both `O(n)`, with one having low complexity and the other with high complexity. It seems your question is more about code complexity — adding some cascaded if/else decisions will increase complexity but won't (by itself) change the `O`

Comment: okay , i am not talking about complexity of code i am talking about time complexity which is the same as big O(worst case) for the code. sorry that i didn't clear that up

Comment: As soon as you get deeper than a couple of `else if` levels your code should really be using a `switch` statement. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch

Answer (score 1):

It remains `O(n)`. Think of big O as "as n changes, how does the runtime length of the algorithm change?" Since n changes the number of iterations of a regular loop, you always add one loop iteration for each addition to `n`, so it's linear (`O(n)`).